# Excel - Index/Match returns 0 for blanks, want to skip blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below excel formula that takes input from `sheet1`, indexes and matches information on `sheet2`, and gives a `sheet2` value on `sheet1`. Sorry if that is confusing. This works, but it seems to choose 0 when indexing column C on `Sheet2` when it is blank. Instead, I would like to skip the blanks. Is this possible?

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!C2:C5000,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet2!G2:G5000=$J2)*(Sheet2!H2:H5000=$K2)*(Sheet2!A2:A5000=$E2)*(Sheet2!Y2:Y5000<=$A2)*(Sheet2!Z2:Z5000>=$A2)*(Sheet2!X2:X5000<=$B2)*(Sheet2!W2:W5000>=$B2)*(Sheet2!AA2:AA5000>=($C2/0.9)),),0)),"Does Not Exist")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I updated the formula to have `&Sheet2!G2:G5000<>` and it works!

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!C2:C5000,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet2!G2:G5000=$J2&Sheet2!G2:G5000<>"")*(Sheet2!H2:H5000=$K2)*(Sheet2!A2:A5000=$E2)*(Sheet2!Y2:Y5000<=$A2)*(Sheet2!Z2:Z5000>=$A2)*(Sheet2!X2:X5000<=$B2)*(Sheet2!W2:W5000>=$B2)*(Sheet2!AA2:AA5000>=($C2/0.9)),),0)),"Does Not Exist")`